# How to solve battling Type & Warning popups in Intellij Scala editor

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, when you hover of a variable, it will helpfully show you the type above it:

[image]

And if you have an error or warning, hover will helpfully show you a warning below it.

[image]

However, most of the time the warning is related to a variable, so you get a millisecond of warning popup which is then replaced by the type

[image]

[image]

Unlike the above images, usually there isn't enough time to read the warning. Is there a way to defeat this behavior or change which one of the two winds the pop-up war?

Comment: Don't use the mouse, but use keyboard shortcuts to open the required popup.

Comment: I know, i know.. I fall back on the crutch of mouse too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Preferences -> Scala, there is an option named 'Show type info on mouse motion with delay'. Change the delay, or uncheck the box.

[This StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822197/intellij-idea-scala-type-info) is somewhat related.

Comment: I had to turn it off, since delaying it only helps so much. But using referenced question i figured out how to get to the type Info via the keyboard, which is better anyhow.