# Show tooltip on variables with type in Intellij with Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is there any way so that IntelliJ shows a tooltip with the type of a variable when you are programming with Scala?

I know that Eclipse has this feature. I have been looking for in the settings and I didn't find it.

Comment: Tooltip appears when mouse over variable with Ctrl pressed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA scala type info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822197/intellij-idea-scala-type-info)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`File` / `Settings` / `Languages & Frameworks` / `Scala` / `Editor` / `Show type info on mouse hover after, ms ...`.

[image: Scala settings]

Answer (score 2):

When you have your cursor on variable, use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>.
By cursor I mean the caret, not mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS IntelliJ 16.x, I observed that the compiler warning/error tooltip takes precedences to the type info tooltip. To force the type tooltip to show, use `View > Type Info` menu option or `ctrl + shift + p` (the default keymap) when the cursor is on the element you want to inspect.