# IntelliJ: Highlight the type of a variable on hover

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

In `Eclipse`, if you place the cursor on any variable, a small popup box will appear containing the type (class) of this variable, how can I have the same in `IntelliJ`?

Comment: [like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7858871/2817802)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By placing cursor on a variable and hitting `Ctrl-Q` you'll find all the documentation regarding this variable, including type.

Comment: `Cmd + J` on mac

Comment: I came here looking for the same thing for PyCharm and Ctrl+Q also works there :)

Answer (score 7):

For IntelliJ 15, the "Quick Definition" option worked for me. On Macs pressing Command-Y is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Either "Quick Definition"  or "Quick Documentation" (F1) works for me.