# print type of variable in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there a neat method could print the class name of a variable in Scala?

Sometimes I see `val result = foo(a,b,c)`, since method `foo` may return different types of object and if I could print class type of result, it will be great.

Comment: In intellij you can use `alt` + `=`

Comment: @Łukasz, thanks and vote up, and I mean in console when program is running dynamically, since types are decides by running value dynamically. :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Quick and dirty trick I often use

```
val result: Nothing = foo(a,b,c)
```

The compiler will raise an error, providing you information about the actual return type it found.

Example from the REPL

```
scala> val foo: Nothing = 42
<console>:1: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(42) // <---- this is what you care about
required: Nothing
      val foo: Nothing = 42
```

---

If you use an IDE, you may use more "sophisticated" options:

- Scala IDE: http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/typingviewing/show-type-of-selection.html
- IntelliJ: [How do I view the type of a scala expression in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858588/how-do-i-view-the-type-of-a-scala-expression-in-intellij)

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, vote up. Is there a way to print type dynamically since the method `foo` has different types of return dynamically and will decide at run time.

Comment: @LinMa, that's a very different question than the one you asked :) I definitely need a more comprehensive example to give an appropriate answer

Comment: If you want a real runtime class just use `result.getClass`. `Set(1).getClass` would output `class scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1`

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, vote up and let me mark your reply as answer first. Then ask more. :))

Answer (score 24):

Use `Object.getClass` method.

See [Scala Cookbook](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch06s04.html)