# Evaluate expression in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I want to know if there is a way in intellij to know the type of a val with a shortcut or a button?

For instance:

```
val t = 3
```

If i select t and do a certain shortcut, can I know that t is ant integer?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I view the type of a scala expression in IntelliJ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858588/how-do-i-view-the-type-of-a-scala-expression-in-intellij)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can select your val or var and press Ctrl + Alt + e
This will add to your code the type of your val.
On your exemple, you will get:

```
val t: Int = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [How do I view the type of a scala expression in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858588/how-do-i-view-the-type-of-a-scala-expression-in-intellij), `Alt + =` on expression should work.

Another option would be `Ctrl + Q` - quick documentation lookup. It could be used nearly anywhere in editor, and is capable to show documentation for type, type of variable, etc.