# when will idea show scala type and how to force make it happen?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

when I write scala code in idea, sometimes it will show the datatype like this:
[image]

but sometimes it will not show like, for example:
[image]

I want to know how it happened, can I force to make it happen?

Comment: Not sure of the rule to display it (there's probably a setting) but by default I noticed it displays types when you are chaining more than 2 calls and each call is on its own line.

Comment: Btw you can select some expression and use Alt + = to know the type.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858588/how-do-i-view-the-type-of-a-scala-expression-in-intellij

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I view the type of a scala expression in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858588/how-do-i-view-the-type-of-a-scala-expression-in-intellij). For the future It is first link on right panel

Answer (score 0):

For recent/current Intellij that should be: `Alt` + `=` (click on what you want highlighted first)

Per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7858871/5065400