# Public method must have explicit type

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, methods, build

I am fairly new to Scala and am having a build error which states `Public method must have explicit type`. Just wanted to know if anyone has come across this kind of error and if so how to fix it?

```
def pk = primaryKey("passive_prompts_primary_key", (uuid, promptType, trigger))
```

Is where the error is forming

My best guess is to add the return type in but I am not sure how to do that

Answer (score 4):

You should specify the return type because the method `pk` is public (instead of `???`)

```
def pk: ??? = primaryKey("passive_prompts_primary_key", (uuid, promptType, trigger))
```

It's hard to say what exactly to write here instead of `???` because only you can know what type `primaryKey(...)` returns.

Normally `Public method must have explicit type` should be a warning, not error. Probably you have switched on in `build.sbt` something like `-Xfatal-warnings` (Scala 2.12) or `-Werror` (Scala 2.13). One of options is to switch it off but probably this is not recommended because it's a useful option.

Now about how you can find yourself the type of `primaryKey(...)` (in order to know what to write instead of `???`).

- You can look at the definition of `def primaryKey...`.
- Alternatively you can start the REPL with `sbt console` and write the right hand side of `pk`, something like

```scala
scala> import SomeObject._ // where primaryKey, uuid, promptType, trigger are defined

scala> primaryKey("passive_prompts_primary_key", (uuid, promptType, trigger))
```

The REPL then write the value and type of `pk`.

[image]

- Or you can use functionality of IDE. I'm pressing `Alt+Enter` in ItelliJ Idea and choose "Add type annotation to definition".

[image]

But Idea can sometimes guess types incorrectly.

- Or you can use self-defined `getType` in the project

```scala
// add to build.sbt: libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, Type, typeOf}

def getType[T: TypeTag](t: T): Type = typeOf[T]

println(getType(
  primaryKey("passive_prompts_primary_key", (uuid, promptType, trigger))
))
```

- Also there is Scalafix rule that adds explicit return types

https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/docs/rules/ExplicitResultTypes.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858588/how-do-i-view-the-type-of-a-scala-expression-in-intellij https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386964/i-want-to-get-the-type-of-a-variable-at-runtime